# ViewChild is null because it is not in dom (NGIF), is there a way to write a function to run when it is found?

Tags: dart, angular-dart

My design:

I have a Tab, which leverages NGIF, so the child content is not in the dom.  The issue is that the inner component requires a subscription set up.  Is there a way such that my ViewChild, when not null, can run a function?

```
@ViewChild("fooId")
MyCustomClass foo;

StreamSubscription sub = null;
```

To me, I was thinking that I would need to do some sort of while loop, with a delay to periodically check foo to see if it is not null.

```
setUp() async {
  while(sub == null){
    if (foo != null){
       sub = foo.onChanged.listen((_)=>_func());
    }
    await new Future.delayed(new Duration(seconds: 1));
  }
}
```

but it seems kinda dirty.

Is there a way to set up in your init file to do something akin to:

```
ngOnInit(){
  // foo.when( () => foo !=null, (){ 
  //   sub = foo.onChanged.listen((_)=>_func());
  // });
}
```

Obviously that is in pseudocode, but i thought there might be a better option than some polling code in order to keep checking nullness.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make `foo` a setter:

```
MyCustomClass _foo;

@ViewChild("fooId")
set foo(MyCustomClass value) {
  _foo = value;
  ...
}
```

Comment: I was unaware you could use set in conjunction with Viewchild.  Ill give it a gander.  I was thinking that the property foo was essentially a getter for the HTML data, so it would have issues with setting while being essentially a getter

Comment: No, `@ViewChild()` only uses the setter. If you need access to `foo` from the template, you can add a getter `foo` as well. I just omitted the getter part because normally it is redundant.

Comment: Sorry, what i meant to say is that I thought using a ViewChild was inherently a getter, that only attempted to get the Controller when you accessed it.  The fact that you can couple it to the set function to essentially monitor the state of it, was new to me because I figured it was only determined during access, and didnt think i could use `set` to essentially monitor it